# JNI: dealing with a complicated C++ class

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a 3rd party Win32 dll, written in C++, which I need to load in my eclipse java project and call some methods from it. What is problematic - all the classes which I really need from this dll have virtual functions. I've created a dummy C++ project, which received all the stuff via static linking and via my self-defined C++ class. Everything is working in my C++ world. Now I want to load my dummy dll (which in turn loads all other stuff I need) in my java project. The code in cpp world looks like this (I've mixed up .h and .cpp for simplicity):

```
class Dummy : public VirtualClassFromLib
{
   public:
   //...
   //some standard stuff here
   //...
   void method1()
   {
      VirtualClassFromLib::function1();
   }

   void method2()
   {
      //a header is loaded with #include
      AdditionalStructureFromHeader object; 
      VirtualClassFromLib::function2(object);
   }

   void virtual_function()
   {
      std::cout << "Cool, now you are not virtual";
   }
   //...
}
```

where `function1` and `function2` are not virtual in the base class and `virtual_function` is.

I'm a newbie in JNI and as far as I understood, I should write a "mirror" class with the same method's and other stuff's names in my java project. **Question:** how to deal with this `VirtualClassFromLib`? Like, this `VirtualClassFromLib` has a very complicated structure with a wide usage of self-defined structures in the original dll. Or don't I need to "mirror" that completely to java project? I don't get it from examples and tutorials in the Internet.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to mirror the entire class hierarchy? Do you actually need to access anything that isn't provided by `Dummy`? If so, can you add a new method for that to `Dummy` so that all you have to worry about in your Java and JNI code is to interface with `Dummy`?

Comment: @Michael you mean  it will be enough in java world just to mirror Dummy (so in java JNI code it will be a single class without extending any other)?

Comment: That seems like a good starting point.

Comment: You can't pass C++ classes to JNI. But you can wrap your C++ member calls into C functions instead, to use in Java.

Comment: @Michael thanks, seems to be a working way.

Comment: @armagedescu isn't it the same as with JNA? Make extern "C" functions and call them? I thought that the diffuculty of using JNI compensates with avoiding of adding C-like function callings by trying to "mirror" C++ structures to the java world. What's then the significant difference between JNA and JNI?

Comment: @gehirndienst I don't know what is JNA. So taken a look on Wikipedia, and it looks like a 3rd party opensource wrapper to JNI. In fact it must use JNI somewhere inside. But JNI is the standard method provided by Java.

Comment: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo025